# How to obtain the elastic documents that have an array field with more than one value?

Tags: arrays, api, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and I'm trying to query without much success.
I have the following documents in my index:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index_text",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "alvaro",
          "cars" : [
            {
              "model" : "opel"
            },
            {
              "model" : "renault"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index_text",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "pepe",
          "cars" : {
            "model" : "opel"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

What I want is to obtain the documents that have more than one car.
I have tried this among many other things:

```
GET index_text/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc['cars'].value > 2"
    }
  }
}
```

The result ever is:

```
"caused_by" : {
  "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason" : "No field found for [cars] in mapping with types []"
}
```

What I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html), to filter documents based on the provided script.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['cars.model.keyword'].length > 1",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67198142",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "alvaro",
          "cars": [
            {
              "model": "opel"
            },
            {
              "model": "renault"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Ooouu YEEES!! Thank you so much. Is working

Comment: if i can return the documents when it have two more cars, i use this "doc['cars.model.keyword'].length > 2" but not working :`(

Comment: @A.Gomez which version of elasticsearch are you using ?

Comment: im using 7.10.2 version

Comment: @A.Gomez When you use this `"doc['cars.model.keyword'].length > 2"`, what error are you getting ?

Comment: aaaah im so sorry, its working. I have the same data {'opel', 'renault', 'opel', 'renault'} so not return data. Your first answer its working. Thanks you again and so sorry

Comment: @A.Gomez its okay :-)